# VSTS - Uno with Xamarin iOS Build error for C# 7.1 feature while LangVersion is properly set

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, uno-platform

When building on vsts (windows hosted machine) I have the following error:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operand 'default'

However, in my project I have:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <LangVersion>7.1</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Moreover, on my machine it does build (in Debug AND Release modes).

UPDATE

The error first appeared while I had the following:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
  <LangVersion>7.1</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
  <LangVersion>7.1</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Note that this is a library and that I do multi-targeting (`netstandard2.0;xamarinios10`) but I don't see why it should matter.

UPDATE2

I tried

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <LangVersion>7.1</LangVersion>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

Looking in the logs I see:

```
/reference:/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Xml.Xsl.Primitives.dll /debug- /debug:portable /filealign:512 /nologo /optimize+ /out:obj/Release/xamarinios10/MyApp.ViewModels.dll /target:library /warnaserror- /utf8output /deterministic+ /langversion:latest /analyzer:/Users/vsts/.nuget/packages/uno.ui/1.31.0-dev.8/analyzers/Uno.Analyzers.dll MyViewModelA.cs MyViewModelB.cs... Parameter.cs ReactiveGroup.cs "/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs" obj/Release/xamarinios10/MyApp.ViewModels.AssemblyInfo.cs /warnaserror+:NU1605
2018-06-27T20:11:28.5184750Z MyViewModelA.cs(105,89): error CS8310: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operand 'default' [/Users/vsts/agent/2.134.2/work/1/s/MyApp.ViewModels/MyApp.ViewModels.csproj]
```

So I think it may not be a build error but some kind of [Uno](https://github.com/nventive/Uno) Analyser error.

Side note: it is strange that the log mentions `uno.ui/1.31.0-dev.8` as I had upgraded the package (see below). As if there were some caching involved I don't know how.

```
<PackageReference Include="Uno.UI" Version="1.31.0-dev.79" />
```

UPDATE3

I can't copy the full log here but here the `csc` command for the project that fails to build:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.8.1/lib/mono/4.5/csc.exe /noconfig /unsafe- /checked- /nowarn:1701,1702,1705 /langversion:latest /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:__IOS__;__MOBILE__;__UNIFIED__;TRACE;RELEASE;XAMARINIOS1_0
```

UPDATE4

Thanks to @[JeromeLaban](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26346/jerome-laban), who provided me with that [link](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.8.0/) about Mono 5.8.0, as it shows that version of mono is compatible with C# 7.0 only.

However, the [specs](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-image-generation/blob/master/images/macos/macos-Readme.md) of the MacOs queue say that there is [Mono 5.10](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.10.0/) installed and that version is up to C# 7.2.
So the next question (and I wrote a dedicated [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091175/vsts-xamarin-ios-build-how-to-choose-the-mono-version-to-use)) is how to specify the mono version to build with.

Comment: What build step do you use? Did you select the right VS version? Is the agent running VS 2017?

Comment: Yes it's all fine. It usually builds. I had the error just once I used that '==default'  feature.

Comment: The agent is the hosted vs2017.

Comment: Did you set the `LangVersion` for both your Debug and Release build configuration, as they go separately in the .csproj file?

Comment: Are you sure they have to be separated? Not specifying a building config (as in the question) seems to work on my machine.

Comment: I mean; if you explicitly set them they go in the .csproj as `<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' "><LangVersion>7.1</LangVersion></PropertyGroup>` and the one for release will be missing. On local pc, one mostly does a debug build; may try a local release build.

Comment: When I first saw the error, they were separated (debug, anycpu and release, anycpu). They were BOTH 7.1. But as I build for ios I thought the problem was with anycpu so  from two nodes I made one (as in the question). Btw it's a library with no other build configuration in the csproj.

Comment: I did try release build on my pc said in the question.

Comment: Which version do you see being applied in the VSTS MSBuild output/log; `csc.exe ... /langversion:7.1`?

Comment: "csc" or "langversion" or not present in the build ios log. Btw the build task is xamarinios.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Xamarin, but assume it uses csc.exe(?). What appears if you set the build verbosity more explicit, eg. verbose?

Comment: Was on phone yesterday and safair couldn't find csc and lanversion on the logs. However today, back on pc, I see langversion:7.1

Comment: Could you share your build definition and detailed log? Please don't mix your and your company's privacy information.

Comment: This looks like the csc compiler is not the right one. I agree with @ceceDong-MSFT, with larger logs, particularly the csc.exe command line that would help.

Comment: that's a big log I don't see myself copy pasting it here. How can I share it differently?

Comment: I edited the question with the csc command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [xamarinios vsts task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/XamariniOSV2) that I run on the hosted vsts MacOs queue runs [mono 5.8.0](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.8.0/) (even though [mono 5.10.0](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.10.0/) is installed on that queue as per [specs](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-image-generation/blob/master/images/macos/macos-Readme.md)). And version 5.8.0 is compatible up to C# 7.0 so it cannot run C# 7.1 code.