# VSTS - Xamarin iOS Build - How to choose the mono version to use?

Tags: xamarin.ios, mono, azure-devops, csc

I'm building a Xamarin iOS project on the Hosted macOS Preview queue of VSTS.
The log shows that it uses mono 5.8.0. However, the queue [specs](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-image-generation/blob/master/images/macos/macos-Readme.md) show that mono 5.10.0 is installed.

The question is how can to choose the version of mono to use (amongst those installed) to build a xamarin ios project on vsts?

UPDATE

Itried the following after @[valdetero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1134836/valdetero)'s answer

```
- task: XamariniOS@2
    displayName: 'Building iOS'
    inputs:
        solutionFile: '**/*.sln'
        configuration: 'Release'
        mdtoolFile: '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.10.1/bin'
```

However, I got that error:

```
[error]Xamarin.iOS task failed with error Error: Unable to locate executable file: '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.10.1/bin'.
```

Comment: Do you try to set Mono Runtime environment variables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/questions/xs-mono-runtime?

Comment: I can't find which variables to set. Would you know?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Xamarin, but you may check `-bind-to-runtime-version` parameter to the `--aot` command line option: http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=man%3amono(1)

Answer (score 0):

In your Xamarin.iOS task, open *Advanced*, check *MSBuild*, and look at *build tool path*. Specify an installed version of mono here. I used this for an old project where I can't build it with Mono 5. Here's what I have in the box:

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/**4.8.1**/bin

Put that entire path in the box.

Comment: On your *build machine*, what versions are listed in the folder `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/` ? (Open Finder -> (Top Menu) Go -> Go To Folder)

Comment: This is a vsts hosted machine not one I can access directly (see the specs link in the question).

Comment: What version of the task are you using?

Comment: Are you implying it is version 2.* of the task?

Comment: Yes, that's what the number after the @ indicates (you can view the yaml of a task or an entire build definition that you are creating manually by clicking on the top right "view yaml" link).

Comment: Any info on this issue?